# How could I take from another list after randomly selecting from the first one? (Python, I need to show the code)

Tags: python-3.x

print("A " + (random.choice(sales)) + " catches your eye.") I'm taking from this list: sales = "coke can","pot of instant noodles","chocolate bar","lottery ticket" and I'd like to make another list of stats (i.e. a coke can heals 25hp) and take from that list.

(program randomly selects 'lottery ticket,' so show lottery ticket stats from stats list as well as showing name.)

Comment: Please edit your post and use triple backticks \`\`\` to format your code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Effectively, this is an indexing problem. `random.choice()` gives you the item. But you need the *index* to look up the item in the second table. Lists have an actual index function. So you could do something like this:

```
mychoice = random.choice(sales)
print("A " + mychoice + " catches your eye.")
myindex = stats.index(mychoice)  # this will be the index or element number
mystat = stats[myindex]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary:

```py
stats = {"coke": 25, "soda": 30, ...}
```

Access the values using the `dictionary[key]` syntax. (e. g: `stats["soda"]` -> `30`)

For way more on dictionarys, check out [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)

Comment: It's worth noting that for dictionaries, the _value_ in the key/value pair can be just about anything. So you could use a string as OP has.  Dictionaries is a good solution. But you could take it one step further and make the `sales` list a dictionary with the thing as key and the stat as value. You could select a random choice with random.choice(sales.keys()). Then you wouldn't need a separate index look up like in my answer.